# Regex to match only the first line?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to make a regex match only the first line of a text? So if I have the text:

This is the first line.
This is the second line.
...

It would match "This is the first line.", whatever the first line is.

Comment: There are many many types of regex and technologies using regex; please specify the relevant ones in your tags.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

that's sounds more like a job for the filehandle buffer.

You should be able to match the first line with:

```
/^(.*)$/m
```

*(as always, this is PCRE syntax)*

the `/m` modifier makes `^` and `$` match embedded newlines. Since there's no `/g` modifier, it will just process the first occurrence, which is the first line, and then stop.

If you're using a shell, use:

```
head -n1 file
```

or as a filter:

```
commandmakingoutput | head -n1
```

*Please clarify your question, in case this is not wat you're looking for.*

Comment: How do I do the same thing in Oniguruma syntax?

Answer (score 34):

In case you need the very first line no matter what, here you go:

```
 \A.*
```

It will select the first line, no matter what.

Comment: This is the easiest, works in Sublime Text 3 if anyone cares.

Comment: This is the most accurate solution.

Comment: Is this a joke :) ? It will match anything from the capital letter A to the end of the line (or end of the string)

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can.

Example in javascript:

```
"This is the first line.\n This is the second line.".match(/^.*$/m)[0];
```

Returns

```
"This is the first line."
```

---

**EDIT**

Explain regex:

`match(/^.*$/m)[0]`

- `^`: begin of line
- `.*`: any char (.), 0 or more times (*)
- `$`: end of line.
- `m`: multiline mode (. acts like a \n too)
- `[0]`: get first position of array of results

Answer (score 3):

There is also negative lookbehind function (PowerGREP or Perl flavor). It works perfectly for my purposes.
Regex:

`(?<!\s+)^(.+)$`

where

- `(?<!\s+)` is negative lookbehind - regex matches only strings that
  are not preceded by a whitespace(s) (\s also stands for a line break)
- `^` is start of a string
- `(.+)` is a string
- `$` is end of string