# Return nth line

Tags: php, regex

How do I return the nth line of a string in RegEx?

For example, if the string is:

```
This is line 1
Some other stuff
Return me!
```

How would I have it return the third line without matching text that is in the third line?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689512/regex-to-match-only-the-first-line) to return the first line but I am not sure how to modify it to return any other line #

Comment: Regular expressions, as a formalism, have no concept of line numbers.

Comment: This is a bad use case for regexes. What language are you using? The pseudocode `string.split("\n")[2]` is guaranteed to be simpler.

Comment: Which language? [Perl?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) [Ruby?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) [Python?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: I edited OP. It is PHP.

Comment: ok then use `$arr = explode("\n", $input); echo $arr[2];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good case for using regex. You can simply try this as @anubhava suggested:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
echo $lines[2];
```

If you really want to use `regex`

```
$text="asdsa
asdas
sadas";

preg_match_all("|.+|",$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);
echo $matches[0][2];
```

http://ideone.com/mGRsdA

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it. This will only capture the line you want to return. However, dynamic's solution of using explode is more readable/maintainable.

The `$lineNumber` is using an offset of 0 for the line numbers.

```
$subject = "This is line 1\r\nSome other stuff\r\nReturn me!";

$lineNumber = 2;
preg_match("/(?:.*(?:(?:\r?\n)|(?:\r\n?))?){" . (($lineNumber < 1) ? 0 : 1) . ",". $lineNumber ."}(.*(?:(?:\r?\n)|(?:\r\n?))?)/", $subject, $results);

echo $results[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\K` construct.

```
 #  '/(?:.*\r?\n){2}\K.*/'

 (?: .* \r? \n ){2}         # Nth - 1 lines
 \K                         # Do not include previous in match
 .*                         # Nth line
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 34 , len 10 ) 
Return me!
```

Comment: awesome! This saved me! Can't believe it took so long to find this regex and can't believe I couldn't figure it out.